# Find relative line number for invalid JSON

Tags: python-3.x, simplejson

I was trying to decode a particular JSON string using `simplejson` python library.

```
invalid_json = """
{
  "numbers": [
    1,
    2
    3
  ],
  "boolean": true,
  "null": null,
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "string": "Hello World"
}

"""

print(json.dumps(json.loads(invalid_json), indent=4 * ' '))
```

I induced error in `numbers` array in the string by removing `,`. When it fails as per the [documentation](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/4b1dab370f8a32aaa3f9140c38645093d3287b82/simplejson/scanner.py) it should give me the line number where is failed with respect to the `pos`. The line number always depends upon the file where the data is stored.

Error msg

```
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter or ']': line 6 column 5 (char 35)
```

Since there is no `,` after 2 in the numbers array, it starts counting up the lines starting at 0 to the top of the file. In this case its 6(I excluded the new lines and import statements in the pasted code above.)

Is there a way to get line number relative to the string instead of the whole file?

Comment: in your code you are using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), not `simplejson`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov actually there is a import statement at the top `import simeplejson as json`

Answer (score 0):

The line number is relative to the  the string not to the file. You can check it by adding empty lines in your source code before the sting definition which will not change the place of the error report.

The fact that the line reported is 6 not 5, is because the way parsers work is it report the error at the point it find there is an error, not at the place the error should be corrected. (By the way the first line of the json string is a line of zero length which go form `""""` to the end of line )

For example in  the following  code similar to your original code, the parser has no way to know it is valid until it reach the line 6. In the same way in your original code the parser know that there is a problem only at line 6.

```
valid_json = """
{
  "numbers": [
    1,
    2
    ,3
  ]
}

"""
```

In general parse error, the fix for error is often few lines before where the error is marked. The line written should be considered more than an hint than an exact position.